# "NameError: uninitialized constant" when using Rails' many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I have the following models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts, :through => :account_holders 
  has_many :account_holders
end

class AccountHolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :people
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, :through => :account_holders 
  has_many :account_holders
end
```

However, I am getting issues when using this relationship.  Account.first.account_holders works just fine, but Account.first.people returns:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Account::People
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2204:in `compute_type'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2200:in `compute_type'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:156:in `send'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:156:in `klass'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:73:in `find_target'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:353:in `load_target'
    from /Users/neil/workspace/xx/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:139:in `inspect'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

belongs_to requires the singular form. In `AccountHolder`:

```
belongs_to :person
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and like the answer above indicates, it got fixed when I changed the belongs_to symbol value in the junction table to singular (removed the 's' in the end of the name).

In my exercise, I have:

guy.rb

```
class Guy < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :junctions
  has_many :girls, through: :junctions
end
```

girl.rb

```
class Girl < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :junctions
  has_many :guys, through: :junctions 
end
```

junction.rb

```
class Junction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :girl_id, :guy_id
  belongs_to :girl   # girls wouldn't work - needs to be singular
  belongs_to :guy    # guys wouldn't work - needs to be singular
end
```

This many-to-many relationship then works...